# multidimensional key-pair array with json_decode (Clickbank IPN v.6.0)

Tags: json, multidimensional-array, clickbank

This is an example of the instant payment notification (IPN) I receive from clickbank:

```
$decrypted = {"transactionTime":"2014-10-06T14:49:00-07:00","receipt":"********","transactionType":"TEST","vendor":"comclub","role":"VENDOR","totalAccountAmount":1.00,"paymentMethod":"VISA","totalOrderAmount":1.00,"totalTaxAmount":0.00,"totalShippingAmount":0.00,"currency":"USD","lineItems":[{"itemNo":"1","productTitle":"A passed in title","shippable":false,"recurring":false,"accountAmount":1.00}],"customer":{"shipping":{"firstName":"TEST","lastName":"USER","fullName":"Test User","email":"testuser@somesite.com","address":{}},"billing":{"firstName":"TEST","lastName":"USER","fullName":"Test User","email":"testuser@somesite.com","address":{}}},"version":6.0,"attemptCount":1}
```

so I do `$order = json_decode($decrypted);`

Now I want to get the individual variables out.

At first, it works fine.  For example, I can do

```
$transactionTime = $order->transactionTime;
```

but when I get to the 2nd-level stuff with lineItems, I'm at a loss.

I've tried all kinds of things:

```
$itemNo = $order['lineItems']['itemNo'];

$itemNo = $order['lineItems']->itemNo;

$lineItems = $order['lineItems'];
$itemNo = $lineItems['itemNo'];
```

but nothing seems to work.

I've also tried

```
$order = json_decode($decrypted, TRUE);
```

but that didn't work either

Does anyone know how to get the itemNo variable for example?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried doing a `var_dump($order)` to show you the structure?  It would show you that it's an [array of objects](http://ideone.com/wCGau6).

Answer (score 0):

You've decoded the JSON as an object, so you'll need to treat it as one.

To access `lineItems`, you'll need `$order->lineItems`.  You should also note that `lineItems` is an *array of objects* and handle it accordingly.  For example `$order->lineItems[0]->itemNo`.

[Here's a demo.](http://ideone.com/4mGkvH)

In the future, use `var_dump` if you're unsure of an object or array's structure.  It will help you tremendously.